# Retrieve data from webpage to Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am working on creating a bot to get a list of drugs from webpage.

The first step is to enter Start Date and End Date and hit the Submit button.
The page opens a list of drugs and my next step is to retrieve the list of drugs in a table format.
Is there a way I could get data from webpage to excel or Blue Prism collection?

Could someone please suggest a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to accomplish this would be to spy the table on the page and use a Read stage with the action "*Get Table*", which will load the data into a collection.